# Not able to connect to Aerospike on localhost

Tags: aerospike, nosql

After installing aerospike on localhost, I am not able to set any value in it thorugh cli. 
I am successfully able to run the same command on an ec2 instance where I have installed aerospike.

```
krishan@L-krishan-Tech:~/softwares/aerospike-server$ telnet localhost 3000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.

krishan@L-krishan-Tech:~/softwares/aerospike-server$ cli -h localhost -n test -o set -k Aerospike -b address -v "Mountain View, CA 94043"
Transaction did not complete for some reason:  timed out
Marking bad:  BB9BF10CB55DBE0   ('127.0.0.1', 3000)
cluster says: no good hosts, really
failing request because no good hosts
set failed,  -1


krishan@L-krishan-Tech:~/softwares/aerospike-server$ cli -h <ec2instanceip> -n test -o set -k Aerospike -b address -v "Mountain View, CA 94043"
succeeded:  key = Aerospike  set=   bin= address  value= Mountain View, CA 94043

[aerospike@ip-<ec2instanceip> aerospike-server]$ cli -h localhost -n test -o set -k Aerospike -b address -v "Mountain View, CA 94043"
succeeded:  key = Aerospike  set=   bin= address  value= Mountain View, CA 94043
```

The only difference that I found is, I am getting this warning in my localhost logs, which is not there in my ec2 instance.

```
Feb 12 2015 10:43:30 GMT: WARNING (paxos): (paxos.c::526) Different number of namespaces (expected: 1, received in partition sync message: 3) between nodes in same cluster ~~ Please check node configurations
Feb 12 2015 10:43:30 GMT: WARNING (paxos): (paxos.c::2917) unable to apply received state in partition sync request from node bb94e8e61bbf4e
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
(paxos.c::526) Different number of namespaces (expected: 1, received in partition sync message: 3) between nodes in same cluster ~~ Please check node configurations
```

This log line shows that there are multiple servers running in your environment with the same heartbeat settings. This same heartbeat setting tells the nodes to try and form a cluster, but the nodes fail to form a cluster since namespace definition is different on them.

You should change the heartbeat IP/port combination on the localhost aerospike config to change its heartbeat setting, such that it does not try to form a cluster with other nodes.